# How to insert list as parameter from powershell to SqlPlus

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, sqlplus

I have a query which is like this in a file :

*script.sql*

```
select * 
from test_table
where name in (&1)
```

*This is an example of query i'm trying to make*

and i execute it with a power shell script which is like this :

```
$names = '''Name1'', ''Name2'''
$params = '"' + $names + '"'
sqlplus -silent $username/$password@$tnsalias "@script.sql" $params
```

*Note that `$names` has a variable list of names*

But then when the script is executed, the parameter get substitute like this :

```
former : where name in (&1)
new    : where name in (Name1)
```

And of course the SQL throws an error.

Why it substitutes the parameter like this ?

How can i achieve what i want to do, so the first parameter is a list of strings which will be used in the `where name in(&1)` clause. My goal is that the sql will be 
`where name in ('Name1', 'Name2')`

The SQL is executed on Oracle 11 if that can help.

Comment: Sorry, in my script the quoting is correct. Here i just put an exemple to simplify what i want to do. I will edit my question. However, you mean that i don't need the double quotes to wrap the names list ?

Comment: If you are calling sqlplus in PowerShell, double quotes that are not literal tell PowerShell to expand everything inside and the resulting expansion will be a string. Single quotes surrounding text tells PowerShell to treat everything inside literally (except escaped characters) as a string. In your case, PowerShell interprets `$names` to be a string. Does sqlplus require literal double quotes to be passed to it? If you did something like `$names = '"''Name1'',''Name2''"'`, then the string would include the surrounding double quotes. You also have a space between the names. Does sqlplus care?

Comment: As far as i know, sqlplus parameters require double quotes to include white spaces and others (espcially if you have multiple parameters) so i guess they are required here as i want the list to be one single parameter. I will update my question to include the goal that i want. in SQL, the space should not be a problem but for sqlplus i don't know (i tested and it didn't change the result)

Comment: Sorry it's another copy, error. In my actual script it is ```&1```. I will again fix my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for powershell

```
$username_dba = "system"
$password_dba = "manager"
$tnsalias_db = "es"
$names = "'''Name1'',''Name2'', ''X'''"
$params = '"' + $names + '"'
$sqlfile = "@sqltest.sql"

Write-Host  $names
Write-Host  $params

C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2\sqlplus  $username_dba/$password_dba@$tnsalias_db  $sqlfile  $params
```

Output powershell:

```
C:\upwork\stackoverflow\param_sql>powershell .\sql_param.ps1
'''Name1'',''Name2'', ''X'''
"'''Name1'',''Name2'', ''X'''"

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri Nov 15 11:46:49 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

old   1: select sysdate from dual where DUMMY in (&&1 )
new   1: select sysdate from dual where DUMMY in ('Name1','Name2', 'X' )

SYSDATE
---------
15-NOV-19

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

Example for bat file.

```
@echo off
set user_name=system
set password=manageresmd
set net_service_name=esmd
set param1='''test1'',''test22'',''X'''

C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2\sqlplus.exe  %user_name%/%password%@%net_service_name%  @sqltest.sql %param1%
pause
```

Output bat file:

```
C:\upwork\stackoverflow\param_sql>sqltest1.bat

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri Nov 15 11:50:58 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

old   1: select sysdate from dual where DUMMY in (&&1 )
new   1: select sysdate from dual where DUMMY in ('test1','test22','X' )

SYSDATE
---------
15-NOV-19

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: So the solution is by using double '&' ?

Comment: This magic is by extra double quotes. `$names = "'''Name1'',''Name2'', ''X'''"`