# How to call and execute a SQL+ file (Oracle DB) with parameters from BATCH or SHELL

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I need your help.
I have an SQL file (Oracle DB) like:

```
drop user &1 cascade;

CREATE USER &1 IDENTIFIED BY &2
DEFAULT TABLESPACE Cmpny_USR TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;

grant alter session,
      create cluster,
      create database link,
      create procedure,
      create sequence,
      create session,
      create synonym,
      create role,
      create table,
      create trigger,
      create view
  to &1;

alter user &1 quota unlimited on Cmpny_INDX;
alter user &1 quota unlimited on Cmpny_USR;
alter user &1 quota 0K on system;
```

With a batch or shell file, I want to automate the process to drop and create the same user. So if I pass a parameter to the batch file like "user1", I want that the input is passed to the sql file. The sql script should be executed with this parameter.
My latest batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
PUSHD \\%~P0

:ask
set /p portnr=Please select user to be deleted: 
echo User with %portnr% will be deleted. To continue press j, else n. 
set /p jodern=j or n:
timeout /t 3

if "%jodern%"=="n" goto ask
if "%jodern%"=="j" goto execute

:execute
???
```

Comment: Why do you want to drop existing user? You will drop all his objects.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I want to "update" them and clean the data. So at first, I drop them and after that I create them again.

Comment: What if someone enters something other than `j` or `n`? for instance, `J`? Consider to use [`choice`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) rather than `set /P`…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858117/how-to-insert-list-as-parameter-from-powershell-to-sqlplus/58873308#58873308

Answer (score 0):

Your '&1' is simply the first command line parm passed to sqlplus.

So, with this simple sql script, doit.sql:

```
prompt You entered &1
select '&1' from dual;
```

Start sqlplus, passing it the name of the script to execute followed by the command line parms:

```
C:\>sqlplus estevens/****@myddb @doit heresmyparm

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Tue Dec 22 08:33:24 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Dec 22 2020 08:33:06 -06:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Automatic Storage Management option

You entered heresmyparm
old   1: select '&1' from dual
new   1: select 'heresmyparm' from dual

'HERESMYPAR
-----------
heresmyparm

SQL>
```